# header hidden on slider and page scroll visible

Tags: scroll, menu, slider, hidden

Please find the below link:

http://vehtri.com/demo/test/one-page/1.html

I require to hide the header on slider and visible only on page scroll, can any anybody help me please.

Below is the example:
http://www.motionplanets.com/

Comment: Hi professionals, Still waiting for your support on my question. I would appreciate if somebody helps me out as soon as possible, I am pending on the website completion only because of this issue.

Thanks,
Naveenkumar Murugeshan